# How to use react-native submodule properly?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to move some shared functions to git submodule and I am facing an issue that I can't overcome.

I have a simple react-native CLI project and git submodule inside with npm package uuid.
I've created the function:

```js
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
    
export const generateId = (): string => uuidv4();
```

But when I try to import the function from the submodule, I am receiving the error: "**Native Module not found**".

It seems that the submodule doesn't have a react-native environment, but when I install **react-native** in the submodule I receive another error: **Invariant Violation: Module RCTDeviceEventEmitter is not a registered callable module (calling emit)**

Seems like a very easy task and there should be some best practices how to create such a submodule.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that having `react-native-get-random-values` as a dependency in your submodule is requiring some react-native API calls, try moving that import to your main react-native app code (index.js) and use only javascript dependencies in your submodule. If you really need to add other dependencies that use react-native in the submodule, I think you would need to recreate it as a react-native library https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup